# Stylelint - Making CSS Appears Before Subclass Definition

Tags: stylelint

is there a rule in stylelint to make it so CSS appears before any subclass definitions?

i would like something like this to be invalid:

```
.some-class {
  .some-sub-class {
    background: red;
  }
  border: 1px;
}
```

I would like this to be correct.

```
.some-class {
  border: 1px;
  .some-sub-class {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

my stylelint setup is very basic and the file `.stylelintrc` only contains the following:

```
{
  "processors": [
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-recommended",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components"
  ]
}
```

does anyone know if there is a rule for what I am trying to do on stylelint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`order` rule](https://github.com/hudochenkov/stylelint-order/blob/master/rules/order/README.md) in the [`stylelint-order` plugin pack](https://github.com/hudochenkov/stylelint-order/blob/master/README.md) to ensure declarations come before nested rules.

You'll need to install the plugin pack first:

```
npm i --save-dev stylelint-order
```

Then update your configuration object:

```
{
  "processors": [
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-recommended",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components"
  ],
  "plugins": ["stylelint-order"],
  "rules": {
    "order/order": [
      "declarations",
      "rules"
    ]
  }
}
```